# Loop ends with no reason

Tags: python

I am trying to solve problem 4 in project  Euler which is:

**A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.**

The initial code that I wrote is:

```
def check_reversed(number):
    number = str(number)
    if number == number[::-1]:
        return True

for x in range(100,1000):
    for y in range(100,1000):
        if check_reversed(x*y) == True:
            print x,y,x*y
```

For some reason the second loop stops at number 583 and outputs the wrong answer. When I change the range though of the second "for" loop to (584,1000), it outputs the correct answer. 
My question is why does the second loop ends at number 583?

**EDIT : SOLVED: (Thank you for your help!)**

```
def check_reversed(number):
    number = str(number)
    return number == number[::-1]

max_pal = 0
for x in range(100,1000):
    for y in range(100,1000):
        if check_reversed(x*y) == True:
            if x*y > max_pal:
                max_pal = x*y

print max_pal
```

Comment: You can reduce `check_reversed` to `return number == number[::-1]` instead of using `if`..

Comment: It might be that you're getting a palindrome answer, but not the largest. But that is strange that it stops...

Comment: Don't use `== True` in an `if` test; that is what `if` is **for**.

Comment: You seem to be getting all the palindromes, not just the largest. Also, 583 happens to be the largest value of Y for the largest value of X that produces a palindrome.

Comment: What do you mean, it stops? It's not stopping. (995,583) is indeed the last one in the order you printed. The last one you get when you change the range of the y loop does appear in the output of the unmodified version, just earlier.

Comment: Also, don't use equality for booleans, just use them, like `return number == number[::-1]` or `if check_reversed(x*y):`

Comment: I think you're just seeing the last line of output. I ran it [here](http://repl.it/NOu) and it spat out thousands of lines, it didn't just stop.

Comment: FYI this is a one-liner in Python. `print("{product[1]}*{product[2]} == {product[0]}".format(product=max([(x*y,x,y) for x in range(100,1000) for y in range(100,1000) if str(x*y) == str(x*y)[::-1]])))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your second loop doesn't end at `583` at all; `583` just happens to be the highest `y` **for `x = 995`** that is a palindrome.

Two lines earlier, your code prints:

```
993 913 906609
```

which clearly contradict your analysis.

You need to track the maximum *result* and not assume that the maximum *`x`* gives you the answer.

Note that there is little point in testing the same numbers for `y` each loop; no need to test the product of `range(100, 1000)` when combinations will do:

```
from itertools import combinations

def check_reversed(x, y):
    number = str(x * y)
    return number == number[::-1]

x, y = max((c for c in combinations(range(100, 1000), r=2) if check_reversed(*c)), 
           key=lambda c: c[0] * c[1])
print x, y, x * y
```

Comment: One of these weekends I need to spend a crunch session learning `itertools`. I posted a one-liner above but it's slow as crud since it's running 808,201 multiplications and 1,616,402 string casts and building a list of 800,000 tuples. Itertools would be much quicker.

Comment: @adsmith: you are also falling into the product trap; you only need to test unique combinations here; e.g. less than half.

Comment: True! And to be fair if the largest palindrome as a product of 3-digit numbers was a perfect square, `itertools.combinations` won't find it! `print("{product[1]}*{product[2]} == {product[0]}".format(product=max([(x*y,x,y) for x in range(100,1000) for y in range(x,1000) if str(x*y) == str(x*y)[::-1]])))` IS incredibly faster.

Comment: @adsmith: but it is easy enough to chain on `(x, x) for x in range(100, 1000)` if that were the case..

Comment: @adsmith: there are all of 8 palindromic squares (for `[101, 111, 121, 202, 212, 264, 307, 836]`), so the difference is easily covered for.

Comment: @adsmith: which is actually interesting, because you could use the largest palindromic square as a starting point to narrow down the search space for the largest palindromic number made from x-digit numbers, I suspect.

Comment: Number theory makes me happy :)

Comment: Hrm, for 4 digits, that number is 2636 so that doesn't cut down the space all *that* much.

Comment: Yes, but for arbitrarily large numbers it's MUCH easier to do `def largestPalindrome(digits): start = max( [x for x in range(10**(digits-1),10**digits) if str(x*x) == str(x*x)[::-1]] );return max([(x*y,x,y) for x in range(start,(10**digits)) for y in range(x,(10**digits)) if str(x*y) == str(x*y)[::-1]])` although it's still a MASSIVELY expensive function. Any way to check palindromes without string casting?

Comment: @adsmith: don't use `max()` to find the largest square; loop *backwards* from the highest number with `next(x for x in xrange(9999, 999, -1) if check_reversed(x, x))` instead. No need to test them all. I am not aware of a faster method than using string testing here. And the largest square palindrome actually helps far more than I realized. Starting at 2636 eliminates 2/3rds of the search space.

Answer (score 0):

your loops just work fine because the last two numbers in your conditions are 995 583
however this script solves your problem

```
def check_reversed(number):
    number = str(number)
    if number == number[::-1]:
        return True

temp = 0

for x in range(100,1000):
    for y in range(100,1000):
        if check_reversed(x*y) and temp <= x*y:
            temp = x * y
            print x,y,x*y
```